# embed image in html and save for offline view (ie)

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, embed, offline

Is it possible to embed an image in my html code and make it avaible in offline mode. My goal is to create an html file without any other files associated with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML

You'll need a proper DataURL for your image. Try a utility like http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker to get the DataURL, which you can then copy into your html.

Comment: Ok, and how do i generate this tag?